# Shortest Syntax To Use numpy 1d-array As sklearn X

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I often have two `numpy` 1d arrays, `x` and `y`, and would like to perform some quick sklearn fitting + prediction using them.

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn import linear_model

 # This is an example for the 1d aspect - it's obtained from something else.
 x = np.array([1, 3, 2, ...]) 
 y = np.array([12, 32, 4, ...])
```

Now I'd like to do something like

```
 linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x, y)...
```

The problem is that it [expects an `X` which is a 2d column array](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit). For this reason, I usually feed it

```
 x.reshape((len(x), 1))
```

which I find cumbersome and hard to read.

Is there some shorter way to transform a 1d array to a 2d column array (or, alternatively, get `sklearn` to accept 1d arrays)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can slice your array, creating a [newaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
x[:, None]
```

This:

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> x[:, None]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Is equivalent to:

```
>>> x.reshape(len(x), 1)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

If you find it more readable, you can use a transposed matrix:

```
np.matrix(x).T
```

If you want an array:

```
np.matrix(x).T.A
```